# Angular Pipe not detecting changes with multiple arguments

Tags: angular, angular5, ngfor, angular-pipe

**So in short I have:**

1. An ngFor displaying an array of cars:

   ```
   <div class="carContainer" *ngFor="let car of 
   cars | carFilter: brand : color">
   ```
2. Search box which is the first argument of the filter.

   ```
   <input type="text" class="form-control" 
   placeholder="Search car brand" [(ngModel)]="searchInput">
   ```
3. Select box which is the second argument.

   ```
   <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="color">
     <option value="red">red</option>
     <option value="blue">blue</option>
     <option value="black">black</option>
     <option value="orange">orange</option>
   </select>
   ```

When I type something in the search bar the filter triggers. I've also confirmed that the value from the select box passes to carFilter. **The problem is...** when I change value in the select box alone the filter **carFilter** doesn't trigger.

If I remove the searchBar argument from the filter then the changes in the select box will trigger the filter. **How do I make the pipe detect changes in both/multiple arguments?**

Comment: Can you provide your carFilter pipe?

Comment: transform(Cars: Car[], color: string, brand: string)


Basically I apply multiple filters on one single Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright after a few trial and errors I figured it out. If you want triggers for multiple arguments such as a **sortBoxInput** and **searchBoxInput**, you have to make two separate filters. I guess it's obvious for those who are more used to angular but I'm a newbie.

So I split my single filter into two, which are searchFilter and sortFilter.

Then I changed the html to:

```
    <div class="carsContainer" 
    *ngFor="let car of cars | searchFilter : brand | sortFilter : color">
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you're not receiving the arguments correctly.

```
transform(value: string[], ...args: any[]): string[] {}
```

make sure that your are receiving an array with the value in the first arguments and the array of properties on the second one.

Comment: [Take a look at this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pipe-arguments)

Comment: transform(Cars: Car[], color: string, brand: string)